# Moving the Labelling of an arrow up / Math mode

Tags: equations, amsmath, arrows

I have labelled an arrow and would like to steer the height of the labbeling.

```
$\stackrel{ number one}{\Leftrightarrow}$
```

produces an arrow that is located very close to the labelling. Moving it upwards would be nice.

Thanks.

Regards,

Arjen

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `\strut`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  $\stackrel{\strut number one}{\Leftrightarrow}$
  $\xLeftrightarrow[ 〈sub〉 ]{\strut 〈super〉 }$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bonus is `\xLeftrightarrow` from `mathtools`.

Comment: Of course if you want to write real text above the arrows, `$\stackrel{\strut \text{number one}}{\Leftrightarrow}$` is much better.

Comment: @moewe: True. I took the risk of assuming that it may not be text :)